# Which method will be called when the iOS device turn into Landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I know that I can return YES to support Landscape mode in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. But I would like to display a new view, when the user turn the device into landscape mode, how can I do so? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observer this event [UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW38)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
           selector:@selector(orientationDidChange:)
           name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

A useful technique for just this case is, to present a new modal view controller with a "fade" transition from your current view.  You can do this in reaction to `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` as mentioned previously by Aaron.

Answer (score -1):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```